# Data mismatch between slave and master

Tags: sql, database

New to Database and just wondering on a high level idea on this:

What happens if there is a data mismatch between slave and master dataset, i.e Few records in slave cant be matched back to master dataset.

Whats the consequence of such a scenario, how do I find more information on what data is missing?

Just a basic explanation will be fine. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you talking about?

Comment: SQL I would say

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: I do not think of slaves in SQL server, server itself is a master :). anyways i guess u mean parent and child tables or master table and a staging table. you have options to use `look up` in ssis or use merge in `sql`

Comment: Ya as in I have two datasets for example, the dataset in question has values which cant be matched to a much bigger parent/master dataset. What do I do in this case ? How do I find what is missing and what should I do?

Comment: There are various options, a simple option would be using a left join . I guess u have primary keys aligned for join condition, are you able to give us some sample data ?. Find the missing data from first data set match it to master table and update or insert in the first data set

Comment: So which DBMS product **are** you using? ("SQL" is **not** the name of a database product)

Comment: Oracle database 18c buddy